# What are the formulas for the smallest set of circles that overlap the unit circle and have a smaller radius?

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to find smaller circles that fully cover the unit circle.

Below is an example with 4 equal circles that fully cover the [red] unit circle.  These circles have a radius $\sqrt {1/2}$.

1. Can I do it with 2 or 3 circles?  The circles need not be the same radius, but each radius needs to be less than $1$.
2. For the fewest number of circles, how can I minimise the area in the circles outside the unit circle?

[image: set of 4 overlapping circles]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do it with 3 circles.

$x^{2}+\left(y-\frac{r}{2}\right)^{2}=\frac{3r^{2}}{4}$

$\left(x+\frac{3^{.5}r}{4}\right)^{2}+\left(y+\frac{r}{4}\right)^{2}=\frac{3r^{2}}{4}$

$\left(x-\frac{3^{.5}r}{4}\right)^{2}+\left(y+\frac{r}{4}\right)^{2}=\frac{3r^{2}}{4}$

[image: 3 circles]