# Given 4 circles of radius r, find smallest radius r such that the four circles can cover the unit circle completely.

Tags: geometry

I have given myself an exercise to prove the disk covering problem up to n = 4. The details can be found here: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiskCoveringProblem.html

I have solved up to n = 3, but am struggling for n = 4. I suspect that the four discs will be arranged so that their centers create a square, but don't have anything rigorous yet. Can I please receive a hint?

Comment: Erich gives the solution, but all he says about it is that it's trivial. https://erich-friedman.github.io/packing/circovcir/

Comment: Hint: In order for $4$ discs of radius $r$ to cover the unit disc, they need to cover the unit circle.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks for the link but I want to understand why, when placed symmetrically like that, those circles have the radius that they do.

Comment: @achillehui Thank you for the hint! I played around with it a bit more and realized that the diameter of each of the circles was sqrt2. For example, the diameter of one of the circles would be from (0,-1) to (1,0), leading to the solution! Do you know if theres a rigorous way to prove why the circles should be placed symmetrically at each corner for the optimal solution or is that something only a computer can figure out?

Comment: When you intersect a disc of radius $r < 1$ with unit disc. Its intersection with unit circle is an arc. Let's call the length of the arc as $\theta$. Since the two endpoints of the arc is at a distance $2\sin\frac{\theta}{2}$ apart and lies within the smaller unit disc,  $2\sin\frac{\theta}{2} \le 2r \implies \sin^{-1}r \ge \frac{\theta}{2}$. In order for 4 such discs to cover the unit circle, you need $4\theta \ge 2\pi$ and hence $\sin^{-1}r \ge \frac{\theta}{2} \ge \frac{2\pi}{8} = \frac{\pi}{4} \implies r \ge \sin\frac{\pi}{4} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reasons of symmetry one would set the centers of the 4 circles at the horizontal and vertical axes,
at coordinates $(x,0)$, $(0,x)$, $(-x,0)$ and $(0,-x)$ for some $x\ge 0$. They cover the unit disc if the
intersection of two of these circles is at the rim of the unit circle, which by the symmetry chosen is a point $(y,y)$
for the two circles at $(x,0)$ and $(0,x)$,
which is $(1/\surd 2,1/\surd 2)$ because according to Pythagoras for the unit circle $y^2+y^2=1$.
Then the squared distance from $(x,0)$ to $(y,y)$ is (Pythagoras) $(y-x)^2+y^2=r^2$. The Task is to minimize $r$ by moving $x$ around. The first derivative of $r^2$ with respect to $x$ is $2(y-x)(-1)$. Setting this to zero gives $x=1/\surd 2$ and $r=1/\surd 2$.

This is already known from [What are the formulas for the smallest set of circles that overlap the unit circle and have a smaller radius?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4560113/what-are-the-formulas-for-the-smallest-set-of-circles-that-overlap-the-unit-circ?rq=1)

Comment: This is the exact and correct answer. who downvoted it?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it was very comprehensive.